# restart after recompile invalid objects in ORACLE

Tags: oracle, weblogic

if weblogic service was currently up already, after recompile the invalid objects in ORACLE, do we have to restart the service?

Answer (score 0):

no, you don't. Oracle objects are available immediately after recompile, you don't need even to reconnect

Comment: thanks Sayan. Just to confirm, is it correct that if we don't recompile manually the invalid objects, oracle will automatically recompile it on use? will it affect anything if we don't do recompile before the execution (eg:stored procedure execution)